# Put wizard navbar on top position

Tags: primefaces, navbar, wizard

I'm working with a wizard component. The navbar is in the botton but my boss wants me to put it in the top of the wizard,I thought that it was an attribute or tag to do it straight forward but I have been reviewing the documentation and I should be wrong (I only found the showNavBar tag).

Is there a way to do it without css or jquery? (we have some problems in the application setting css when working with some components so I would like to avoid it).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in either of the two ways:

### 1 - Extending the [WizardRenderer](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/wizard/WizardRenderer.java)

By extending the `WizradRenderer` you can change the order of the encoding.

In the [original Renderer](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/wizard/WizardRenderer.java#L158) the `encodeContent(facesContext, wizard);` is called before `encodeNavigators(facesContext, wizard);` so it's pretty much simple, extend you custom renderer, change the order of the calls.

```java
public class ExNavWizardRenderer extends org.primefaces.component.wizard.WizardRenderer{

   @Override
   protected void encodeMarkup(FacesContext facesContext, Wizard wizard) throws IOException {
       ResponseWriter writer = facesContext.getResponseWriter();
       String clientId = wizard.getClientId(facesContext);
       String styleClass = wizard.getStyleClass() == null ? "ui-wizard ui-widget" : "ui-wizard ui-widget " + wizard.getStyleClass();

       writer.startElement("div", wizard);
       writer.writeAttribute("id", clientId, "id");
       writer.writeAttribute("class", styleClass, "styleClass");
       if(wizard.getStyle() != null) {
           writer.writeAttribute("style", wizard.getStyle(), "style");
       }

       if(wizard.isShowStepStatus()) {
           encodeStepStatus(facesContext, wizard);
       }
       // encode the navigators before the content
       if(wizard.isShowNavBar()) {
           encodeNavigators(facesContext, wizard);
       }

       encodeContent(facesContext, wizard);

       writer.endElement("div");
   }
}
```

Update your `faces-config.xml`

```xml
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.WizardRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.projectPackage.ExNavWizardRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

---

### 2 - jQuery

In your `document.ready` you can change the DOM, for example this would do the same as the Renderer:

```javascript
$('.ui-wizard-step-titles').after($('.ui-wizard-navbar'))
```